# How to build a program in Launchpad which has dependencies from external repository?

Tags: compiling, dependencies, launchpad

I am trying to build my program in Launchpad. Problem is, it depends on webkit2gtk (>= 2.6.2) and it isn't on my repository (because I don't maintain it), and it isn't on Ubuntu repositories either, but it is in [GNOME 3 Staging PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging). And every time I'm trying to build my program it fails this way:

```
[MANUALDEPWAIT] Dependency wait on lgw01-02
Missing build dependencies: webkit2gtk (>= 2.6.2)
Started 7 minutes ago
Finished 6 minutes ago (took 59.9 seconds)
```

Is there any way to specify this package it is this repository? Or any way to clone package from repository and add it to mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on either of the "View Package Details" link (will take you to [this](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging/+packages) page) and click on "Copy Packages" on the right side. Select which packages you want to copy and make sure the destination PPA and series are set correctly.

Comment: They've got packages only for Vivid and Utopic. Copying these packages to my repository worked. The only not working thing is Trusty release. This repository doesn't have packages for Trusty, so I tried to copy Utopic series to my repository as Trusty, but builds are still failing because of the same error (although Utopic and Vivid packages of my app are building fine now).

Comment: Use `backportpackage` to backport the packages from Utopic to Trusty. Don't copy the packages from Utopic to Trusty as library ABI's likely changed between the two. You should also remove the packages you copied to Trusty.

Comment: can you provide any information how to do it in Launchpad? I didn't find any info about it.

Comment: oh, I think I found some info: http://opensourcehacker.com/2013/03/20/how-to-backport-packages-on-ubuntu-linux/. Thanks for the tip ;)

Comment: Note that you may need to specify `-d` (the release to backport to, which is Trusty in your case) and `-s` (the release to backport from). Note that you also need to add your own PPA to the list of PPAs installed on your system.